# JS - How to find the index of deepest pair of parentheses?

Tags: javascript, nested, parentheses

I have a string:
`"5 * ((6 + 2) - 1)"`
I need to find the deepest pair of parentheses and their contents.

I've googled a lot and I can't find anything specific to finding the index. A lot of solutions found how many levels there are, and things like that, but nothing was really helpful. I was thinking of counting the layers, and then using a loop to solve and repeat solving until done, but it seems like this would be really slow.

I have no idea where to start, so I haven't written any code yet.

I want a function to return 5, the string index of the deepest set of parentheses. I also need to do the same for the deepest ")", since I need the pair. Example:

```
const deepestPair = (str) => {
    // Find deepest pair of parentheses
}
deepestPair("(2(5)4)(3)") // Returns [2, 4], the indexes of the deepest open/close parentheses
```

Comment: will the pattern always be same? right now its ("(A(A)A)(A)")

Comment: @Vortex no, the pattern will be different

Comment: @AlvinTheodora 2 is the index of the deepest opening parenth, and 4 the index of the deepest closing parenth.

Comment: What should the output be for `(2(5)4(6)7)(3)` where there are multiple equally as deep?

Comment: @Ivar the first one to match the highest level (5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check opening and closing parentheses and use a counter for getting the most nested indices.

```js
const deepestPair = str => {
    var indices,
        max = 0,
        count = 0,
        last;
    
    [...str].forEach((c, i) => {
        if (c === '(') {
            last = i;
            count++;
            return;
        }
        if (c === ')') {
            if (count > max) {
                indices = [last, i];
                max = count;
            }
            count--;
        }
    });    
    return indices;
}

console.log(deepestPair("(2(5)4)(3)")); // [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` `([(])[^()]+[)]` to match `(` followed by one or more characters that are not `(` or `)` and closing `)`, `/[)]/` to match closing parenthesis, return indexes of matches

```js
const deepestPair = (str, index = null) => 
  [index = str.match(/([(])[^()]+[)]/).index
  , str.slice(index).match(/[)]/).index + index]

console.log(deepestPair("(2(5)4)(3)"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to get the **deepest pair using two stacks**. It also returns the depth of the pair in a structure, with the `open` and `close` indices.

It uses a `singles` stack to hold the open parenthesis found so far, and another stack (`pairs`) for matched parenthesis.

Each time a closing parenthesis is found, the last open parenthesis is popped from the `singles` stack and put in the `pairs`.

Then you just have to sort this `pairs` stack using the `depth` property and get the first item.

```js
const deepestPair = str => {
  const singles = [];
  const pairs = [];

  [...str].forEach((c, i) => {
    if (c === '(') {
      singles.push({ depth: singles.length + 1, open: i });
    } else if (c === ')' && singles.length) {
      pairs.push({ ...singles.pop(), close: i });
    }
  })

  pairs.sort((a, b) => b.depth - a.depth);

  return pairs.length ? pairs[0] : {};
};

console.log(deepestPair('(2(5)4)(3)'));
console.log(deepestPair('(2(5)(1)(11(14))4)(3)'));
```

If you want to get an array as the result you can replace the last line by this:

```
return pairs.length ? [pairs[0].open, pairs[0].close] : [];
```